# HTML5 Canvas Set Top/Left

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I can easily set the `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` properties.  I cannot find the right JavaScript syntax to set the offset of the canvas using top and left.  I have tried setting these properties on the canvas directly and on the bounding rectangle.

I would like to be able to set the top and left offset so that I can reposition the canvas when a user clicks on a point.

If `canvas.width = 600` works just fine; why doesn't `canvas.top = 80` work?  I am confused.  Thx for your help.

Comment: Possible for you to recreate the problem you are having in a working demo please. Thank you.

Comment: `canvas.top` is nothing. The canvas element does not have an attribute by that name. Are you talking about CSS?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the top position of the canvas, you need to wrap the canvas inside of another div with absolute positioning. Then set the position of the canvas to be relative to its wrapping div. Finally, you can set the style of the canvas.

Make sure you provide units e.g. `px`, `em`, `rem`, `%`, etc...

```js
var panel = document.getElementById('panel');

panel.width = 600;
panel.height = 200;
panel.style.top = '80px'; // Must specify unit.
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  background: #0FF;
}

#panel {
  position: relative;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="panel"></canvas>
</div>
```

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) state:

> The effect of `top` depends on how the element is positioned (i.e., the value of the `position` property):
>
> - When `position` is set to `absolute` or `fixed`, the `top` property specifies the distance between the element's top edge and the top edge of its containing block. (Containing block needs to have property `position: relative`)
> - When `position` is set to `relative`, the `top` property specifies the distance the element's top edge is moved below its normal position.
> - When `position` is set to `sticky`, the `top` property behaves like its `position` is `relative` when the element is inside the viewport, and like its `position` is `fixed` when it is outside.
> - When `position` is set to `static`, the `top` property has *no effect*.

Answer (score 1):

Please try canvas.style.top = "80px";

Comment: As suggested in the other answers below, Please set css position to absolute then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set position to relative or absolute. Have Look at the example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;top: 80px; position: absolute;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, `width` and `height` are html attributes and can therefore be set using `element.width` and `element.height`. However, `top` is a css proberty, not an html attribute - therefore it can only be set using `element.style.top`.

Also, as already pointed out in the other answers, the css `position` proberty has to be either `fixed` or `absolute` in order for `top` and `left` to work.

Answer (score -1):

CSS

```
canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
}
```

JS

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.top = "80";
```

Comment: Please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.